# How $\frac{c\:e^{j\theta}- a^H x}{\|a\|_2^2}a \rightarrow$ $\frac{c- |a^H x|}{\|a\|_2^2 \: |a^H x|}aa^H x$ for $\theta$ to be angle of $a^H x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a paper, there it rewrites this equation

$$\frac{c\:e^{j\theta}- a^H x}{\|a\|_2^2}a$$

into

$$\frac{c- |a^H x|}{\|a\|_2^2 \: |a^H x|}aa^H x$$ if $\theta$ to be angle of $a^H x$, where

$j = \sqrt{-1}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a, x \in \mathbb{C}^n$

---

Sorry, I just don't understand how to derive the latter from former. Please help.

---

My question in other words, how

$e^{j\theta} =  \frac{a^H x}{|a^H x|}$  ?

Comment: What is $j$? What is $c$? What is $a$? What is $x$? What doe $a^H$ mean? Are these complex numbers, complex vectors, something else?

Comment: $j = \sqrt{-1}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a, x \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Also, $a^H$ corresponds to complex conjugate transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from your question what $j$, $c$, $a$, $x$ and $a^H$ are, but I hope this helps:

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The point marked on the circle in the complex plane is $e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle that $z$ makes with the positive real axis. But it is also $\frac{z}{|z|}$, because this is the vector $z$ scaled to lie on the unit circle. After all
$$\left|\frac{z}{|z|}\right|=\frac{|z|}{|z|}=1.$$
This shows that $e^{i\theta}=\frac{z}{|z|}$.

Comment: This explains, thank you so much